# Как правильно определить TimePicker

Tags: java, android, framelayout

У меня есть класс DatePickerFragment и с ним связанная кнопка. В итоге у меня появляется окошко с выбором даты. 
Я хочу сделать такое же окошко, только с выбором времени TimePickerFragment. Т.к. классы похожи, их нужно немного изменить, но у меня что-то пошло не так. В конце я выделил проблемный участок комментариями. Что нужно изменить?

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static  final String EXTRA_DATE =
        "com.diplom.android.diplom.taskIntent.date";

private static final String ARG_DATE = "date";

private DatePicker mDatePicker;

//Передача даты через аргументы = объект дэйт аргумент фрагмента
public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(Date date) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_DATE, date);

    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_DATE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);

    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int mouth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
            .inflate(R.layout.dialog_date, null);

    mDatePicker = (DatePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_date_picker);
    mDatePicker.init(year, mouth, day, null);


    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(v)
            .setTitle(R.string.date_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    int year = mDatePicker.getYear();
                    int month = mDatePicker.getMonth();
                    int day = mDatePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                    Date date = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day).getTime();
                    sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                }
            })
            .create();
}

private void sendResult(int resultCode, Date date){
    if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
        return;
    }

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATE, date);

    getTargetFragment()
            .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
}
```

}

И кнопка, с которой он связан

```
    mDateButton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.task_date_title);
            updateDate();
            mDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                    DatePickerFragment dialog = DatePickerFragment.newInstance(mTask.getDate());
                    dialog.setTargetFragment(TaskFragment.this, Request_DATE);
                    dialog.show(manager, DIALOG_DATE);
                }
            });
```

Мне нужно сделать TimePickerFragment. Вот, что у меня вышло.

```
@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        Date date = (Date) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_TIME);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        //calendar.setTime(date);
//        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
//        mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

       int hours = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
       int minutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity())
                .inflate(R.layout.dialog_time, null);

        mTimePicker = (TimePicker) v.findViewById(R.id.dialog_time_picker);
        mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(new Integer(minutes));
        mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(new Integer(hours));

       // mTimePicker.init(year, mouth, day, null);


        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setView(v)
                .setTitle(R.string.time_picker_title)
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {



                    ....//Вот здесь я не знаю, что сделать, чтобы
                  ......//вернуть нужный мне объект со временем
                    int hours = mTimePicker.getHour();
                    int minuts = mTimePicker.getMinute();
                    Date time = ;
                        sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, time);



                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

    private void sendResult(int resultCode, Date time){
        if (getTargetFragment() == null) {
            return;
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIME, time);

        getTargetFragment()
                .onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), resultCode, intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Берем минуты и часы, переводим в миллисекунды.

**Код:**

```
//Перевели в миллисекунды:
long minutes = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(minutes);
long hours = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(hours);
// Создали дату
Date newDate = Date(hours + minutes);
```

*спасибо **@pavlofff**(у)*

Comment: В коде уже есть колбэк в активити, результат возвращается через `onActivityResult()`. Проблема в вопросе - как упаковать в тип `Date` часы и минуты (а не года, месяцы и дни)

Comment: @pavlofff а чего в секунды все не перевести и в Date кинуть?

Comment: ну это нужно у автора спрашивать.

Comment: Да, верно, как упаковать Time в Date. Что за dismiss()?

Comment: dismiss это после того как вы сделали все что хотели закрывает ваш диалог

Comment: @TimurMukhortov как перевести в секунды и передать date?

Comment: TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(yourMinutes) это в милисекунды переведет ваши минуты

Comment: @TimurMukhortov а к объекту Date как совершить переход?

Comment: @pavlofff так как то

Comment: добавил код в ответ

Comment: ну а потом уже обратную операцию, берете там из этих секунд выделяете часы и минуты

Comment: @TimurMukhortov я понял, а тут появилась проблема. calendar.setTime(date); - кидает нулпойнтер, хотя в datepicker такого нет

Comment: что за проблема?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75916/discussion-between-timur-mukhortov-and-keyjibo).

Answer (score 1):

Это из харди. Сорян за спойлер, но я сделал так:

```
return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(v)
            .setTitle(R.string.time_picker_title)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            clock.set(Calendar.HOUR,mTimePicker.getCurrentHour()); //это экземпляр Calendar
                            clock.set(Calendar.MINUTE,mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute()); //это экземпляр Calendar
                            date.setTime(clock.getTimeInMillis());
                            sendResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, date);
                        }
                    })
            .create();
```

здесь устаревшие методы (getCurrentHour(), getCurrentMinute()), но это легко исправить, стерев слово Current в вызове метода, мне же компилятор не дает это сделать, так как я писал под API от 19, а эти методы поддерживаются API не ниже 23, а проверку условия установленной версии андрюши мне лень было писать. Всем ромашек и поменьше занудств

Comment: Можно пояснить, чем отличаются твои 2 ответа и почему их не стоит написать одним?

Comment: Я нашёл решение, но оно немного другое. Там багов много, я проверю твой вариант, надеюсь он мне поможет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поместите оба варианта кода в один ответ с пояснениями чем они отличаются. Думаю, так будет феншуйнее)

Comment: Я проверил, правда от части. Проблема в том, что DatePicker и TimePicker - сетают разные значения в одну переменную. Я не придумал, как можно сетать дату в переменную без времени, а затем туда же сетнуть время без даты. Выход нашел такой - создать в объекте 5 переменных, которые отвечают за год, месяц, и т.д. и передавать объекту эти значения. Потом их просто поднимать через get. Способ теоретический, и поэтому как проверю - отпишу.